# Google Amp Contact form error when submitting

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

Anyone can help me work out in using the AMP Contact form?
I am doing a subscribe form using Mailchimp and SendEngine and I embedded the form to my HTML page.

Here is the screenshot of the error:

[image: Error when submitting form]

Comment: Google for CORS, you'll find plenty of questions on Stack Overflow that will help you

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a working form so that I can compare it. I dont know where I got wrong

Comment: You are doing an XMLHttpRequest to a different domain than your page is on. So the browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. You need to do something different when you want to do a cross-domain request. A tutorial about how to achieve that is [Using CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/). Please read the related question, I'm voting to close this as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you try to submit to a domain different than your AMP site.

You need to whitelist your AMP domain on your server to enable CORS or contact Administrator if it's a shared hosting for your AMP domain to be whitelisted for CORS. Read further about [CORS on AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/amp-cors-requests).

Also check out [specs on CORS Whitelisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).